# BigQuery - Taxonomy policy tags in INFORMATION SCHEMA

Tags: google-bigquery

Are we able to access information whether a policy tag is applied to a column via querying INFORMATION SCHEMA?

For example, I would like to select all columns that belong to a specific tag in a taxonomy but I can't find a way to do it?

Comment: Hi @Moseleyi,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks kiran.. it's a shame we can't do it but you're right, you still answered that we can't. Hopefully Google changes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using BigQuery console UI to know whether a policy tag is applied to a column or not. According to this [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) it seems like from the information schema we cannot find such details.

However, there is a feature request filed for the [same](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187863659). You can vote for this feature by clicking the `+1` and `STAR` marks to receive updates on it or you can also create a feature request thread in Google’s Public Issue Tracker.

For more information and workaround refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#query_data) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608146/how-to-get-policy-tag-if-bigquery-attribute-from-information-schema/63613771#63613771).